# How can I force require-final-newline nil?

Tags: hooks, local-variables

I'm doing this from `typescript-mode-hook`:

```
(defun disable-final-newline ()
  (setq-default mode-require-final-newline nil)
  (setq-default require-final-newline nil)
  (setq mode-require-final-newline nil)
  (setq require-final-newline nil))
```

I've verified that this code runs when I open a `.ts` file (I can see the output of a `(message ...)` I added to the definition of the function above).  However, after I load the file, I see using `C-h v` that `require-final-newline` is set `t` as a buffer-local variable (the global value is `nil`).  If I then `(run-hook 'typescript-mode-hook)`, the variables get set buffer-local to `nil` as I expect, and saving the file has the behaviour I expected (not adding final newlines).

I've also tried setting these two variables as directory-local variables, without any change in behaviour.

I've searched all the code I can think of and can't find any relevant reference to these variables other than in my own code.  How can I force this variable false in .ts files? (ideally by locating the code that's setting it true)

Comment: If you only want this in behavior in typescript mode, then you can remove the `setq-default`'s. If indeed you ensured that the code runs, then probably the value gets set again somewhere later. You can check this by adding a `(debug-on-variable-change 'require-final-newline) after that last `setq`.

Comment: The debug-on-variable-change is exactly what I was wishing for!  The rest I thought I knew, but thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 2):

The answer in my case turned out to be an .editorconfig file whose existence I was not aware of.  It specifies:

```
insert_final_newline = true
```

@dalanicolai's suggestion to use `(debug-on-variable-change 'require-final-newline)` after my last setq answered this for me very quickly!